# Semiclassical QCD

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, classical-field-theory, semiclassical

The classical Lagrangian density for Quantum ChromoDynamics (QCD) is given by:

$$\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{QCD} = \bar{\psi}_i  \left( i \gamma^\mu (D_\mu)_{ij} - m\, \delta_{ij}\right) \psi_j - \frac{1}{4}G^a_{\mu \nu} G^{\mu \nu}_a $$

Although these equations were formulated in the context of QFT and in that context is where they make sense and have been most studied, I wonder if the corresponding classical equations (Euler-Lagrange equations) have the following properties:

1. Do they predict that asymptotic freedom exists?
2. Do they predict the confinement of color charges?
3. What interesting phenomena do these equations present at the classical level?

Comment: I think quark confinement is a quantum phenomenon. Also, color is a gauge redundancy. It's associated conserved charge is a trivial operator in the Hilbert space. In QFT, there is no such a thing as "color charge".

Comment: What is a particle, like a quark, in a classical field theory?

Comment: I have found one interesting article consideing semi-classical QCD for studying many aspects: *Semi-classical transport theory for non-Abelian plasmas* (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0110104)